# Creating cursor to loop over some fields in SQL server 2008 r2

Tags: cursor, sql-server-2008-r2

Can anyone help me with

How to declare a cursor that contains some values and then cursor should loop over the values. And for each value: i) Have to execute the procedure and insert the data into the table variable ii)And select particular columns from the table variable+timestamp and then inserting them into the another table.

Comment: Have you tried any code, there will be plenty example of cursor usage

Comment: Hi amritpal, Thanks for Replying.

Yeah i have tried many things as i am learner i am not able to do this particular action. I have created stored procedure which takes user input and then give some result. But i want to know how to execute SProc to insert data into temp table as well as how to loop over particular value using cursor.

I just started learning SQL. Help. Thanks.

Comment: visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057464/how-to-process-row-by-row-an-integer-list-sent-to-a-procedure-in-sql-server-2008/29057588#29057588

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you'd want to do this using cursors.  If you can explain what you're trying to achieve there will no doubt be a way to achieve the desired outcome without using cursors.

Cursors conflict with the main premise of the relational model. Using cursors, you apply procedural logic and iterate through individual rows, as opposed to applying set-based logic, where you handle whole sets of rows. With cursors, you end up writing a lot of code with iterations, where you mainly focus on how to deal with data. When you apply set-based logic, you typically write substantially less code, as you focus on what you want and not how to get it.